# Does it violate encapsulation for interface property accessors to be public?

Tags: delphi, oop, properties, interface

When we design a class in Delphi, typically we have private fields (members), private setter and getter methods and a public property. From outside the class, the access of that data is made only by the public property; the users of the class don't even know that a getter method exists.

So the getter and setter methods encapsulate the instance member and the property encapsulates the getter and setter methods.

However, when defining an interface we are exposing those methods:

```
ICounter = interface
  // I wouldn't want to specify these 2 methods in the interface, but I'm forced to
  function GetCount: Integer;
  procedure SetCount(Value: Integer);

  property Count: Integer read GetCount write SetCount;
end;
```

Implementing the concrete class:

```
TCounter = class(TInterfacedObject, ICounter)
private
  function GetCount: Integer;
  procedure SetCount(Value: Integer);
public
  property Count: Integer read GetCount write SetCount;
end
```

Using it:

```
var
  Counter: ICounter;
begin
  Counter := TCounter.Create;
  Counter.Count := 0; // Ok, that's my public property

  // The access should me made by the property, not by these methods
  Counter.SetCount(Counter.GetCount + 1);
end;
```

If the properties encapsulate the getter/setter private methods, isn't this a violation? The getter and setter are the internals of the concrete class and shoudn't be exposed.

Comment: This reads like a rant. What is your question?

Comment: Which bit is confusing you? It makes pefect sense to me.

Comment: -1 for completely changing the nature of the question after you already had three answers to it. I object with your statement that my edit "changed the direction." My edit put your two questions into the title so that the title was a proper question. *Yours* is the edit that changed the direction.

Comment: Sorry about that Rob, but the question was not about "Why can't I access instance members from interfaces", I already know that. The question was "Should interfaces expose internal methods that the properties encapsulate?". The text was real confuse, and my english sucks too.

Comment: "Should interfaces expose internal methods that the properties encapsulate". YES, cause interface members are all public, as explained by @Rob and me in the answers.

Comment: @Ken, how did any version of this post not ask answerable questions? Didn't my original answer address everything asked in the original question? Doesn't the new question ask about a well known object-oriented design principle? Rafael only posted one further comment (not one to every answer), and it seems like it was asking for clarification of what was said in the answer, which is exactly what comments are for.

Comment: I'll delete my comment. I'm not sure I agree the question is answerable, but I seem to have been mistaken (I could swear I'd seen a comment discussing both answers posted at the time, but I apparently was wrong). This still seems to be more of a rant and a discussion of the perceived flaws in interfaces to me, but I seem to be alone in that interpretation. :-) In my defense, see your comment above about the question changing after answers were posted. It's a moving target, because it was an inappropriate question in the first place and it's evolving now, which is also wrong here.

Comment: My last comment was addressed to @RobKennedy. Ran out of room. :-)

Comment: I'm aware your question is about interfaces, and interfaces are as they are supposed to be.

If you need something like you are describing maybe you can use abstract classes or partially abstract classes.

Comment: Properties in interfaces are an ugly hack IMO. Explicitly defining the underlying methods is surely necessary, but it misses their whole point (to simplify things). Besides, having to redefine the property on every implementation of the interface is also ridiculous. You end up having 2 method definitions plus 1 property definition in the interface, plus the same plus the field itself on the class. 7 definitions for a single field, plus the implementation of the getter and setter themselves. Ridiculously high amount of code for such a simple task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Methods are the *primary* way of interacting with an interface. Properties on interfaces are a Delphi-specific extension; they just provide syntactic sugar for the underlying methods. No other language Since methods in interfaces are by definition public, they are not encapsulated by properties. You're not revealing any implementation details by showing that a property is backed by methods because in interfaces, properties are *always* backed by methods, and methods are *always* public. Encapsulation cannot be violated if it was never present in the first place.

Your example concrete class is misleading. First, the property defined there has absolutely no connection to the property defined in the interface. You could define it as read-only, make it directly access data members, make it private, or differ from the interface version in any other way, including remove it entirely, and it would have no effect on users of the interface, lending further credence to the notion that it's the methods that matter in an interface, not the properties. The compiler translates any use of the interface property directly into use of one of the corresponding interface methods, which are already public. The implementing object is never consulted on the matter.

Second, the visibility specifiers on the class are irrelevant. There's no need to make the methods private since they're public on the interface already. However, making them private isn't a bad idea since it encourages proper use of the class via the interface.

You could complain that the accessor methods of an interface should be able to be private, but that's the same as asking for interface methods in general to be able to be private, and that makes no sense. A method that can't be called obviously isn't part of the interface. Recall that interfaces can be consumed by any COM-supporting language, even ones that have no notion of properties, like C and C++. Those languages need to be able to call the accessor methods, too. If the methods were somehow private, the interface wouldn't work in those languages.

---

When a property of a Delphi class refers to a field, that detail is actually part of the class's public-facing interface. Any code that uses that property *knows* that the property is just an alias for the field (even if the *author* of the code didn't know that). If you change the property definition, any code using that class needs to be recompiled so the compiler can generate new code for accessing the property.

When properties are required to be backed by methods, you can't really change the property definition anymore. Only the implementation can change, and so no consumers of the interface need recompiling just because you choose to make a property be calculated on demand instead of read from a stored field.

Comment: "If you change the property definition, any code using that class needs to be recompiled so the compiler can generate new code for accessing the property". Well said, and that is why I consider a good practice to always define properties with method accessors instead of using fields (even simple value properties), because no property re-definition is needed in the future.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about the concrete property having no connection with the interface property, that's misleading indeed. Anyway, it looks a bit contradictory to me. The "Delphi way": keep your getters/setters private and publish only the property. Than the good OOP practice says "program to interfaces, not concrete classes". So, you can't protect you getters and setters.

Comment: But with interfaces, there's nothing to protect them *from*. They're not just an implementation *detail* in interfaces. They're an integral part of how to use the class. Properties, if present, are little more than an afterthought in interfaces because they're not universally usable the way methods are.

Answer (score 3):

> However, Interfaces force the use of Getter/Setter methods:

Because a interface doesn't have a instance, so it can't store data.

> Besides that, Getter and Setter methods are usually private. Defining
>   them at the interface makes them accessible to users of interface. It
>   creates some confusion:

Interfaces don't specify visibility of members. It is up to the class that implement the interface to define which properties and methods are visible and for who they are (protected or public or published).

If you will use your interface only by classes/modules of your own, no problem in change the visibility in the implementing class, although is not a good practice.

> Now, how am I going to set the count: Counter.Count := 0 or
>   Counter.SetCount(0)? Isn't this breaking the encapsulation?

You can set the count property in both ways. If setting it with:

```
Counter.Count := 0
```

The access methods will be invoked the same way. And no encapsulation is break.

**Edited:**

Let me put an example to clarify that nothing break, but could have different behaviors:

Given this implementation of your ICounter interface:

```
  TMyCounter = class(TInterfacedObject, ICounter)
  private
    FCount: Integer;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    procedure SetCount(Value: Integer);
  public
    property Count: Integer read GetCount write SetCount;
  end;

implementation

function TMyCounter.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FCount;
end;

procedure TMyCounter.SetCount(Value: Integer);
begin
  FCount := Value;
end;
```

Some possible uses of your property are:

```
var
  c: TMyCounter;
  ic: ICounter;
begin
  c := TMyCounter.Create;
  try
    //c.SetCount(1); //won't compile, since the setter is private
    ICounter(c).SetCount(1); //it is ok, because the interface method is public
    c.Count := C.Count + 1; //it is ok, cause the SetCount acessor will be invoked
    if Supports(c, ICounter, ic) then
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(ic.GetCount));
  finally
    c := nil;
  end;
```

Therefore, we can conclude:

- Classes have "access specifiers" and this will be always respected
  when accessing the class type;
- Interfaces do not have "access specifiers", and all methods will be considered public when accessing the interface type;

Comment: Aren't interfaces meant to substitute getter and setter methods? That's why the getters and setters are implemented as private and only the property is published. All the VCL is designed that way, it's a way of saying to the user of the class: "Hey user, just use this property, whenever I'm using a getter method or not, is my business, not yours". When I said breaking the encapsulation, I meant that the interface is exposing the implementation internals.

Comment: But they're obviously not internals since they're public by definition. Since all interface properties are backed by methods, you're not revealing any secret implementation details to the consumer by saying that a particular property is backed by a method.